# SharedPreferences will change value after being edited in a Firebase service when the app is in the background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a strange situation with the shared preferences in my application. I am using Firebase messaging service and I would like to set a boolean value to true in shared preferences whenever I recieve a message.

here's a simple code I worte:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(ApplicationConstants.SHARED_PREFRENCES_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(getString(R.string.badge_settings_key), true).apply();
}
```

I access this boolean value later in one of my activities. As you can see I set true for the boolean value in this method.

The strange thing is that when my application is in forground(one of the activites are visible), this works perfectly and whenever I access this value it is still true. But when my app is in background and I recieve a message, the value remains false and will not change. Either the service won't trigger correctly or the shared preferences file will not save correctly.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: what if the user never touches the notificaion and launches the app directly? what can I do for this senario?

Comment: Then there is no need of  notification in first place.

Comment: For my application senario, there is. I want to show the user a notification that something has happend AND set that boolean value in shared preferences

Comment: In that case the issue is, on background your getApplicationContext() is null and the line where you save to preference will not work.Check if the application is visible and if not start activity using intent .

Comment: getApplicationContext() is not null, Check my answer below.

Comment: how did you solve this issue. I am also facing same situation.

Comment: @Saneesh The final solution was that I didn't use the "notification" key in the posted JSON. What I did was to send everything in "data" key and create the notification manually. The problem with the previous approach, as ` Frank van Puffelen` said, was that when the app is in the background and you set a "notification" key, the `onMeesageRecieved` method is never called, hence causing the issue

Comment: @roostaamir I have solved the issue by passing the data to the launcher activity and save it to the   shared preferences  . working fine in both background and foreground. I also use notification key to send the values

Answer (score 2):

`onMessageReceived` will not get called if you app is in background or killed and the notification is sent from Firebase Console.

What happened in your case, you have received the notification but the method `onMessageReceived`was never called and SharedPref is giving you false as default value of any boolean variable.

Solution: 
Don't sent Notification from Firebase Console, use their API.

[Check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947541/what-is-the-difference-between-firebase-push-notifications-and-fcm-messages/37948441#37948441)

**Edit:**

You must not put json key "notification" in the request to make it land in the `onMessageReceived` in all three scenarios of the app: Foreground, background and killed.

Comment: I am using their api and I am using their POST webservice to send a message. I have both data and notification in my message.what should I do to acheive my goal? (I want both the notification and the `onMessageRecieve` with the `data`)

Comment: In order to make it work: you must not put json key "notification" in your request to firebase api but instead use "data". Hard luck.

Comment: but I need the `notification` key in order for it to,you know, notify the user that soemthig has happened and I need the data for internal jobs. what should I do if I want both?

Comment: Ditch the `notification` key, send everything in `data` and extract the message from there and create your own notification and show it to user. Also you  must be getting notification icon issue when sending `notification` key, it will also solve that.

Comment: When your app is backgrounded, notification messages are handled by the system and your `onMessageReceived()` will *not* be invoked. See the text after the JSON block in [this documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications) and the first bullet point in [this documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages).