# How can I make the server actively notify the client of resource change?

Tags: android, firebase, spring-boot, kotlin, push-notification

My client is an android application and the server is a REST server in spring boot, they are both written in Kotlin.
The scenario is that we have multiple clients communicating with the server and writing a resource in the DB. Among these clients, there is a coordinator, which I would like to be informed of each time this resource is updated.

Is PUSH notification a possible solution? If yes, who triggers the notification?
Let's assume that I don't want the Firebase console to launch these notifications.
I have seen these tutorials: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xoJi-ZHmNI) for client and [this](https://blog.mestwin.net/send-push-notifications-from-spring-boot-server-side-application-using-fcm/) for server.
A notification firebase controller is built with its endpoints, does this mean that a request is needed to get these notifications? I am not getting how does it work and if this type of communication is made without polling from the client.

Answer (score 1):

1. Socket -> https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet u can use scarlet to communicate with sever which is similar retrofit
2. FCM -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/37948441/8370216 u can trigger this from your server instead of push notification use data payload  because it gives u more control